# How to assign values from dict with more arguments than function?

Tags: python

I want to use the `**kwargs` syntax to assign values to function inputs. However, my dictionary containing the keywords have more arguments than the function. How can I use dict `p` to provide input values for the fucntion `func`?

```
p = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

def func(a):
    return a

func(**p)
```

This gives an error: `TypeError: func() got an unexpected keyword argument 'b'`

Comment: You could change your signature to `def func(a, **kwargs):` or `def func(a, **_):` to signify you don't care about it.

Comment: If you expect a parameter `a` passed as a keyword argument (per `**p`) and don't care if there are others then you want the suggestion by @Axe319.

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(**kwargs):
    # Extract the 'a' value from kwargs
    a = kwargs.get('a', None)  # You can set a default value if 'a' might not be in kwargs

    # Your function logic here
    return a

# Your dictionary
p = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

# Call the function with the dictionary
result = func(**p)
print(result)
```